# Run Node with Sails from another directory cwd

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line, sails.js

I need to be able to start my Node app, that is using Sails from another working directory:

The usual: `node app`

What I need: `node myfolder/app`

The second way lifts the server, however, none of the assets works. Looks like he is using my current directory as the assets folder (didn't tried api or anything else), but the server get's lifted.

What happens, is that accessing resources, gives me back a `Not Found`.

Is this a issue, or am I doing something wrong?

**Explaining my goal:**

I have a folder with multiple node apps. I'm using pm2 to launch lots of processes, so, my folder structure is like this:

```
Apps
 |- processes.json

 | App1
   |-...

 | App2
   |-...
```

I need to start all the apps from the `Apps` folder, **not** from within the `App1` or `App2` folder. However, it is not working properly with Sails.js. I have tried to run only a single app from another working directory, but the same problem occurs.

Comment: Can you describe your use case a little more?  That is, why do you need to do this?  Is it inside another script?

Comment: @MattBakaitis I'm using Mac OSX 10.9.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, a better answer if you're going to be running things through a process manager would be to change the directory in the Sails app's main file itself.  That is, at the top of the `App1/app.js` file, put:

```
process.chdir(__dirname);
```

that way you won't be starting a different process, and the process manager will be able to monitor output, logs, etc. in the expected fashion.

Not sure if this would be a good thing to have in Sails by default, but we'll look into it!

Comment: I was doing exactly the same thing! thanks for the answer although =)

Comment: you're a god. It works especially for my case when I split my projects into frontend and backend and put in two different folders each one layer deep. I was thinking what I should do with the countless cwds in the dependencies.. Thanks you

Answer (score 3):

Sails does expect you to be lifting the server from within the app directory.  However, you can always write a wrapper script to temporarily change the working directory:

```
process.chdir('App1');
require('child_process').exec('node app.js');
```

Save that in your main Apps directory as `runApp1.js`, and use your process manager to run that instead.

Comment: Shame on Sails... Isn't there another workaround that doesn't requires adding code to the app?

Comment: I will be using `pm2` to manage processes. If it works out of the box, it's better

Comment: @IvanSeidel this is the default for all Sails apps now (it does `process.chdir(__dirname);` at the top of `app.js`).

Comment: After many problems and limitations, I've changed to `geddy.js` framework. A lot less problems... But It's good they fixed it =)